# Read File spark, set field having specific value to null or ""

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm Reading a text file delimited with | . There are some fields having value \N . When read the file row by row to a data-frame, is there any way to make the field having value \N to null or "" .
Code is given below.

```
val inputDf = sqlContext.read.format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "false")
      .schema(myschema)
      .option("delimiter", "|")
      .option("nullValue", "")
      .load("My Input file Path")
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you load the dataframe use the when condition on all the columns in generic way

```
inputDf.select(inputDf.columns.map(c=> when(col(c) === “\\N”,””).otherwise(col(c)).alias(c)):_*).show
```

Answer (score 1):

"DataFrameNaFunctions" can be used for replace value "\N" in all columns with "":

```
df.na.replace(df.columns.toSeq, Map("\\N" -> ""))
```