# Number format exception writing parquet file using Spark caused by some fields having unknown value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I'm reading a text file using spark with the schema below.

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- style: string (nullable = true)
 |-- code: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- state_code: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- post_code: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- mail: string (nullable = true)
```

Here's my Scala code

```
 val myDf = sqlContext.read.format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "false")
      .schema(myschema)
      .option("delimiter", "|")
      .option("nullValue", "")
      .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
      .load("Path to file")
```

Here in this input file some coulmns having value as "\N". I wanted to relplace all coulmn valuse having the value "\N" with empty(""). When I try to write this Data Frame as a parquet file

```
 myDf.na.replace(myDf.columns.toSeq, Map("\\N" -> "")).write.format("parquet").save("path to output")
```

Its throwing an exception

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "\N"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:12)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:80)
```

Any help writing the parquet file by resolving the issue?

Comment: Try this:

 Map("\\\\N" -> ""))

Comment: @SCouto No way still getting same exception

Comment: the Answer is already provided in your previous question. Please check once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52368658/read-file-spark-set-field-having-specific-value-to-null-or

Comment: @ChandanRay Solution not working

Comment: @Juhan what is the issue you are getting solution provided by me. Please check.Lets not have 2 same question opened.

Comment: If the solution provided on your other question isn't working, please update that question instead and clarify with the answers. Please don't ask the same question multiple times !

Answer (score 1):

Guess, exception occurs not in writing, but during reading.

If schema with int fields assigned to CSV file, and field values in file contains "`\N`", such error can occurs.

Guess, you can replace saving in Parquet with other action (show, etc) and get the same exception.

Comment: myDf .na.replace(myDf .columns,Map("\\\\N" -> "")).show()  Also throwing same exception

Comment: please try without "na.replace". Also from yours test obvious, this is not Parquet saving issue, but reading issue, and another fix is required.

Comment: yes even  myDf .show() throws the same exception

Comment: means, schema is not match CSV file structure, and can be corrected.

Comment: Schema is fixed and is there any way to replace the \N when reading the file

Comment: I am not aware about such way. As workaround, schema can be relaxed just for reading, and after reading and replacing "\N", DataFrame can be converted to required schema; but this is another question, guess, for other thread.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20889501)

Comment: My last comment contains answer on question from author last comment "is there any way to replace".

Comment: @Madhur Bhaiya In main question author asked help with exception. In my answer I provided reason for this exception, guess, answer was useful, author followed by advice from answer. No critics or clarification.

Comment: @pasha701 Please add proper context, and details. Currently, the answer seems out of context and informal chat-like.